# store and update an array as json in mysql database laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have values that I want to store in the database, I have declared the type as json and cast it as an array:

```
    protected $casts = [
    'favourites' => 'array'
];
```

however, I'm not sure how to add and update and read the values inside, any ideas?
controller function:

```
public function addtofav()
{
    $id = request()->get('id');
    $user = auth()->user();
    json_decode($user->favourites,true);
    array_push($user->favourites,$id);
    dump('hello');
    json_encode($user->favourites);
    $user->save();
    return response(['id'=> $id],200);
}
```

Comment: what does the output of the ```json_decode``` statement look like?
can you dump that or ```dd()``` it.

Comment: at the moment the column is completely empty, plus I'm calling the function using ajax and dumping doesn't work apparently(I've tried) @YasserSebai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [Laravel documenations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting):

> adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize
> the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent
> model.

therefore, no need to make any encoding or decoding to your values before any update or create, just keep it as an array and Eloquent will take care of that, since you have the $cast array as below:

```
protected $casts = [
    'options' => 'array',
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should use many to many but if you want to use array, you don't encode or decode.

```
public function addtofav()
{
    $id = request()->get('id');
    $user = auth()->user();
    $favourites = $user->favourites;
    array_push($favourites,$id);
    $user->favourites = $favourites
    $user->save();
    return response(['id'=> $id],200);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work, still giving me a 500 internal server error, since I'm calling this in an ajax function

Comment: please dubug it, what is the error first line of 500

Comment: I already write to you, but my answer is not accepted. Thank you